# How to create a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio Code to move the cursor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-keybinding

Regarding Visual Studio Code shortcuts: What is the command Id to move the cursor one space to the right? This way I could create a key binding to accomplish this command.

Comment: which commands are bound to your Arrow keys

Comment: search the key bindings for `cursorRight` to see which key-combo is bound to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `cursorRight`. This is an example of a key binding with this functionality:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+r", "command": "cursorRight", "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

You can change the value of `"key"` and copy-paste the line in the *keybindings.json* file to override the default value for that key(s). Also adjust the attribute `"when"` to your needs.